# "to slam <home> the <home> penalty <home>"

Tags: differences, adverbs

A sentence from "Extra Examples"of item 2 from [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/slam_1):
**(1)** *He slammed **home** the penalty for goal number two*.
To me, it's very strange to see "*home*" in the place where it is.
As far as I understand, "*home*" can't be a noun here because the verb "slam" is not ditransitive.
Therefore, "*home*" is an adverb. Am I right?

I'm removing "*for goal number two*" for it to not distract us:
**(2)** *He slammed **home** the penalty*.
and writing some variants for comparing.

---

If "*home*" is an adverb, why not put it just at a place more appropriate for adverbs, for example at the end of a sentence:
**(3)** *He slammed the penalty **home***.

Is (3) correct?
If not, then why not?
If it is, then what's the difference between (3) and (2)?

---

Also can we make "*home*" an adjective?:
**(4)** *He slammed the **home** penalty*.

Is (4) correct?
If not, then why not?
If it is, then what's the difference between (4) and (2)?

Comment: Why might you think (4) would possibly have the same meaning?  You could say "she hammered the nail in" or "she hammered in the nail" but not "she hammered the in nail"

Comment: @Henry, (2) & (3) mean "_He scored a penalty._". (4) means "_He took a penalty in the home game_." and doesn't tell us if he scored or not. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+home+penalty%2Chome+the+penalty%2Cthe+penalty+home&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) has no examples of *the home penalty* suggesting that nobody has been recorded as giving it any meaning

Comment: Hello, Loviii. You have to be careful when assigning parts of speech.  Many would analyse 'home' here as an adverb (M-W adverb sense 2b is relevant, though many linguists are very wary about completely trusting dictionaries on POS assignment. And indeed, CGEL, with its classification system,  labels it an intransitive preposition.) But in 'She looked up the telephone number', some would class 'look up' as a transitive _multi word verb_ [optionally separable: 'looked the number up'] with _simplex verb_ 'look' and particle 'up'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in your sample sentence, [*home* is an adverb](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/home) and moving that adverb around in the way you've done doesn't change the meaning of the sentence. When you remove the 'extra' parts, the sentences seem very similar:

- He slammed home the penalty.
- He slammed the penalty home.

In the first version, the reader goes from the verb "slam" to a modifer of the verb "[slammed] home" to the object "the penalty". The second version makes the reader jump from the action "slam" to the object "the penalty", then back to a modifier of the action "[slammed] home".

Emphasis in English tends to be found near the start or the end of a sentence; emphasis in the middle of a sentence requires more work, such as inserting a pause before the emphasised word, or saying the word more loudly or slowly. Compare:

- He slammed home the penalty.
- He slammed [pause and say the next word more loudly] home the penalty.

Another thing to consider is the part you threw away. When you put a huge chunk of text between a word and its closely-related component, the meaning stays the same, but sometimes people get lost. Consider this example:

- The mouse the cat the dog the owner petted chased ate had stolen the cheese.

It would be slightly clearer with some brackets and expansion:

- The mouse ([that] the cat ([that] the dog ([that] the owner petted) chased) ate) had stolen the cheese.

That is, the owner petted the dog; that specific dog chased the cat; that specific cat ate the mouse; and that specific mouse had stolen the cheese.

Now compare your proposed modification with respect to the original sentence:

- He slammed home the penalty for goal number two.
- He slammed the penalty for goal number two home.

It's not as hairy as the animal sentence, and still very comprehensible without brackets, but it's ever so slightly more unwieldy than the original.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin No. Compare 'He slotted in the penalty'. 'In' and 'home' are directionals (or arguably resultative locatives). 'She led him a merry dance', which has the same appearance as 'She cooked him a lovely cake', must be analysed differently from the benefactive (two object) way.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth For me, *slam NP home/down/etc* patterns like a transitive verb with a separable “particle” (eg: *break off a piece/break a piece off*), allowing *slam down a window/slam a window down* alternation. Locative adverbials also work: *slammed the door in his face*. Your resultative aspect is important because you can also have **resultative adjectives** like *slam NP shut/closed/tight*.  Normal adverbs like *often* or *loudly* can’t fall between the verb and its object, but they ᴄᴀɴ both follow ᴀɴᴅ precede the VO. I don’t know why no such movement is allowed with *slam a door hard*.